# A path-lookup and write concurrency issue

Tags: linux, concurrency, path

In linux VFS, how is this kind of a situation taken care of: say a process is looking up a file A..got its reference and in the meanwhile the file A is deleted by another process. The first process successfully found A but when it wants to perform operations on it, the file is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a process has successfully called `open` on the pathname of the file, it is assigned a file descriptor. This descriptor has nothing to do with the pathname anymore, so when the name is `remove()`d later, the file can still be read or written to. It also occupies disk space.

Further keywords for your own researching are: unlink, hard links.

But before the file is opened, the obvious will happen, and you cannot guarantee that two successive calls to `chmod` or `open` affect the same file.

This is also the reason that functions like `fstat` or `fchmod` or `fchdir` exist.